# How to Make frame <Leave> event take into consideration all child widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following code that displays a popup windows (no decoration) that shows a listbox of items and their count in a `LabelFrame`.

As this is a popup window, my intention was to hide that window when the cursor moves out of it.

Using the below, the window disappears when the mouse cursor moves away of the frame, but it also disappears when the mouse moves over the `Scrollbar`.

For some reason, the binding the `<Leave>` to the object itself takes the `Listbox` also into account while the `Scrollbar` is not taken.

Why? How can i fix the code so mouse hovering over all widgets of the frame leaves the frame visible, and only when it moves out of the whole frame, it disappears?

```
class ForeachViewer(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.main_frame = LabelFrame(self, text="Total:")
        self.main_frame.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.content_items = StringVar()
        self.group_expansion = Listbox(self.main_frame,
                                       activestyle = 'none',
                                       selectmode='single',
                                       font=text_font,
                                       listvariable = self.content_items,
                                       relief='flat',
                                       highlightthickness = 0)
        self.group_expansion.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nswe")

        self.yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.main_frame, orient='vertical')
        self.yscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='ns')

        self.group_expansion.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)
        self.yscrollbar.configure(command=self.group_expansion.yview)

        self.bind("<Leave>", lambda event : self.hide())
        self.hide()

    def contents(self, content):
        max_length = len(max(content, key=len)) + 5
        self.main_frame.configure(text= " Total Items: %d" % len(content))
        self.group_expansion.configure(state="normal", width=max_length)
        self.content_items.set(" ".join(content))
        self.group_expansion.configure(state="disable")

    def show(self, at_x, at_y):
        self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (at_x, at_y))
        self.deiconify()

    def hide(self):
        self.withdraw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works pretty well with the class type binding :

```
self.bind_class('Toplevel',"<Leave>", lambda event : self.hide())
```

The first argument is the type targeted by the event, it can be 'Button' or the base class 'Toplevel' in your example.